# spring abac with centralized database

Tags: spring-security, abac

I need to have ABAC for my large user base, I want to save the ABAC details in data base like mongodb.

I went through these [1](https://github.com/bipin-yadav/Spring-Security-Demo) [2](https://github.com/jcasbin/jcasbin-springboot-plugin)  details but these links talks about how to make rules in properties file and verify using spring pre authorize.

Is it possible to store these kind of ABC rules in database and use them in a centralized Authorization server before calling the micro service .

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using a recent version of Spring Security, there are [several ways to handle authorization with that framework](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#servlet-authorization). One way I know - but not pretending to be the best - is to implement a custom [AccessDecisionVoter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#authz-voting-based) or, if an AccessDecisionVoter is not enough to fit your needs, a custom (more complex though) [AbstractAccessDecisionManager](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#authz-access-decision-manager). You can find a good tutorial on how to implement, configure and enable your own AccessDecisionVoter on [Tim te Beek's blog](https://blog.jdriven.com/2019/10/spring-security-custom-access-decision-voter/). Then, inside the AccessDecisionVoter's vote(...) method, you may call your external Authorization Server with an authorization request and get a Permit/Deny response.

There is an international (OASIS) standard that defines a syntax/format and semantics for this kind of ABAC authorization request/responses as well as for policies/rules: [XACML](http://docs.oasis-open.org/xacml/3.0/xacml-3.0-core-spec-en.html). XACML also has a [REST Profile](http://docs.oasis-open.org/xacml/xacml-rest/v1.0/cos01/xacml-rest-v1.0-cos01.html) that defines a HTTP/REST API for XACML-based Authorization Servers; and a [JSON Profile](http://docs.oasis-open.org/xacml/xacml-json-http/v1.0/xacml-json-http-v1.0.html) that defines a JSON format for requests/responses as an alternative to XML. Therefore, XACML defines a standard way to externalize authorization to an Authorization Server.

Some of these XACML-compliant servers can store ABAC (XACML) policies/rules in a database, e.g. [AuthzForce RESTful PDP](https://github.com/authzforce/restful-pdp) with a [Policy Provider plugin such as the MongoDB policy provider](https://github.com/authzforce/restful-pdp/issues/2#issuecomment-396666186).